# Limit drag area of scriptaculous draggable

Tags: javascript, draggable, scriptaculous

Im usign this to create a bunch on draggable elements:

```
$$('.box').each( function(item){ new Draggable(item) });
```

How can I limit the draggable area? This way, the boxes can be droped anywhere on the page, and I would like to limit the drag area to their current parent element (I dont think I need to create a droppable). Or, at least, i would like to revert the box to its initial position if its dropped outside it parent.
How can I do this?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably a bit late, but here is my solution:

just add a snap to the draggable item

```
new Draggable('myItem', {
    snap: function(y) {
        return[ (y < 1024) ? (y > 0 ? y : 0) : 1024 ];
    }
});
```

now your item moves just along x.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the drag horizontal or vertical, you can use this:

```
new Draggable('myItem', {
    constraint: "horizontal"
    });
```

Or like bopa said, you can use snap to limit the drag with specifics x y like in this example:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=scriptaculous_14